# CKEditor5 - Append content at cursor position of editor with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, ckeditor5

I am using CKEditor5 classic and document type.

I have a report where I need to enter the parameter of one of the report houses by double clicking on it in the text. For this I need to find the position of the cursor and put the parameter in that field.

Note: The cursor position may be in the middle of the text.

I need to add values to the application with javascript.

```
<div id="ck5_Container_fldDescription" class="ck5_Container">
  <div class="SMK form-control ck ck-content ck-editor__editable ck-rounded-corners ck-editor__editable_inline ck-blurred" tabid="4" name="ck5_fldDescription" subtype="CKEDITOR5" submod="DOCUMENT" id="ck5_fldDescription" dir="rtl" role="textbox" aria-label="Rich Text Editor. Editing area: main" lang="ar" contenteditable="true">
    <h2><strong>asdfsadf</strong></h2>
    <p>asdf</p>
    <p>asdf</p>
    <p>asdf</p>
    <p>as</p>
    <p>df</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
function addText() {
  var editor = document.getElementById("ck5_fldDescription");
  //console.log(editor);
  var RepName = $('#Rep .rowSelected').find("td").eq(1).html().trim();
  //console.log('RepName');
  //console.log(RepName);

  editor.model.change(writer => {
    const selection = editor.model.document.selection;
    const currentAttributes = selection.getAttributes();
    const insertPosition = selection.focus;
    writer.insertText(RepName, currentAttributes, insertPosition);
  });
}

$('#Rep').dblclick(function() {
  addText();
});
```

My code is like above but it doesn't work properly, can you help me???